# How to pass argument to the Mongodb find() function call?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I pass in the query argument to the find() function call ?
Here, in my code below "stocksummaryId" is fed into the app.post call, but this is outside the scope of the MongoClient.connect() call and not visible in the function.

The search query variable comes up as "undefined" inside the MongoClient.connect() !
How can I overcome it and pass it to the connect call ?
Appreciate any inputs.
Thanks

```
app.post('/stocksummary/**', (req, res) => {

   const stocksummaryId = req.params[0];

   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if ( err ) throw err;

        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        // find/query for a certain symbol like  GTX, ATEN, WUBA
        // Below I would like to replace the symbol WUBA with "stocksummaryId"

        const cursor = dbo.collection('stocks_summary').find({ Symbol: "WUBA" }).toArray( function ( err, result ) {
        console.log ( result );
        db.close();
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access outside variable please make a object of MongoClient connection and after connecting database.

Please use query

```
var db = MongoClient.connect(url);
var dbo = db.db("mydb");
const cursor = dbo.collection('stocks_summary').find({ _id: stocksummaryId}).toArray( function ( err, result ) {
        console.log ( result );
        db.close();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @mahesh bhatnagar,
I am not sure if I got it.
I am now getting an error 


    TypeError: db.db is not a function